# MySQL: DELETE CASCADE on a unique composite key set

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, foreign-key-relationship, cascade

I've been digging this for hours, and I'm pretty surprised I haven't find a solid answer to this.  There's gotta be someone doing this.  Maybe I've been searching the wrong keywords.

So, I'm using MySQL, InnoDB (of course) because my question is related to foreign keys and relations.

What I'm trying to do, is to build an ON DELETE CASCADE definition.

As you can see, my table "test_i18n" has a composite primary key, build of test_i18n_id and test_locale.  Neither of these are unique by itself.  But together, they form a unique pair.

Let's call this Table A.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_i18n` (
  `test_i18n_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_locale` enum('en','zh') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en',
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_i18n_id`,`test_locale`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

I now have another table.  For each unique pair in table A, I can add one or more records related to table A.

Let's call this Table B.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_i18_link` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_i18_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `locale` enum('en','zh') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `test_i18_id` (`test_i18_id`,`locale`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Here are just some test data.

```
INSERT INTO `test_i18n` (`test_i18n_id`, `test_locale`) VALUES
(1, 'en'),
(1, 'zh'),
(2, 'en'),
(2, 'zh');

INSERT INTO `test_i18_link` (`test_i18_id`, `locale`, `url`) VALUES
(1, 'en', 'http://www.google.com'),
(2, 'en', 'http://www.yahoo.com');
```

Now, what I want to achieve is, if I delete the first record (1, 'en') from Table A, the first record (1, 1, 'en') from Table B will automatically get CASCADE DELETEd.

However, if on the other hand I were to delete second record (1, 'zh') from Table A, nothing will get deleted in Table B, because such unique pair does not exist in Table B.

Now, before answering, I'd like to make one important point.

I do note that this can be done by adding one PK column to Table A, and have Table B reference that new column instead of the composite key set.  But I couldn't do that for various reasons.  I wanted to see if there is a method to actually achieve this correctly.

Thanks in advance guys!

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: In your Table B, what should be the FK columns are defined as a Unique index. This doesn't sound like what you want. Have you actually defined an FK at all?

Comment: Hi Simon, Table B's FK index would be also a composite pair (`test_i18_id`, `locale`).  I'm trying to do the usual type of relation between 2 tables, where when one row deletes, the other gets deleted together.  The challenge though, so that I don't have one single column that's unique.  It's always a "pair"

Comment: You have found one more reason I do not use FOREIGN KEYS, much less CASCADE.  I prefer to do the task in client code, where I have complete control.

Comment: @RickJames Yes I can do this in php code, done it before, but believe it or not, you're asking for trouble.  While you're the smarter one in the team and always remember to delete child records, 90% of the time ur team members make dumb mistakes and leave dangling records out there.  By using CASCADE DELETE, it puts a level of abstraction, and nobody would ever need to be aware anymore, and they delete happily, flawlessly.  Coding manually is possible, but not comparable to CASCADE DELETE.  Wanna find a way to do that, and if nothing works, I will consider fallback to code level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, with this structure, after countless hours of research and thinking, it's just not possible at the moment, unless there is some bleeding edge stuff that gets released with the next version of MySQL.

So the best thing you can do on the DB level is, like I mentioned originally in my question:

- Add one PK column to Table A, and have Table B reference that new column instead of the composite key set.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the end of your `test_i18_link` table creation syntax:

CONSTRAINT `FK_test_i18n_id` FOREIGN KEY (`test_i18n_id`,`test_locale`) REFERENCES `test_i18n` (`test_i18n_id`,`test_locale`) ON DELETE CASCADE